# Change blog post title on main blog page

Tags: custom-field

Looking to create a custom field to change the titles shown on the blog archive page without effecting them on the actual posts. (The purpose of this is to have shorter titles when viewing all the posts)

I found the following line of code in blog-layout.php.

```
<div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
                    <?php // Render the post title. ?>
                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>

                    <?php // Render post meta for grid and timeline layouts. ?>
                    <?php if ( 'grid' === $blog_layout || 'timeline' === $blog_layout ) : ?>
                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_metadata( 'grid_timeline' ) ); ?>

                        <?php if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta' ) && ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_author' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_date' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_cats' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_tags' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) ) && 0 < Avada()->settings->get( 'excerpt_length_blog' ) ) : ?>
                            <div class="fusion-content-sep"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php elseif ( 'large-alternate' === $blog_layout || 'medium-alternate' === $blog_layout ) : ?>
                        <?php // Render post meta for alternate layouts. ?>
                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_metadata( 'alternate' ) ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="fusion-post-content-container">
                        <?php
                        /**
                         * The avada_blog_post_content hook.
                         *
                         * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_content - 10 (outputs the post content wrapped with a container).
                         */
                        do_action( 'avada_blog_post_content' );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

edit: Also found the actual function:

```
function avada_render_post_title( $post_id = '', $linked = true, $custom_title = '', $custom_size = '2', $custom_link = '' ) {

        $entry_title_class = '';

        // Add the entry title class if rich snippets are enabled.
        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'disable_date_rich_snippet_pages' ) ) {
            $entry_title_class = ' class="entry-title fusion-post-title"';
        } else {
            $entry_title_class = ' class="fusion-post-title"';
        }

        // If we have a custom title, use it otherwise get post title.
        $title = ( $custom_title ) ? $custom_title : get_the_title( $post_id );
        $permalink = ( $custom_link ) ? $custom_link : get_permalink( $post_id );

        // If the post title should be linked at the markup.
        if ( $linked ) {
            $link_target = '';
            if ( 'yes' == fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', $post_id ) || 'yes' == fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', $post_id ) ) {
                $link_target = ' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"';
            }
            $title = '<a href="' . $permalink . '"' . $link_target . '>' . $title . '</a>';
        }

        // Return the HTML markup of the post title.
        return '<h' . $custom_size . $entry_title_class . '>' . $title . '</h' . $custom_size . '>';

    }
```

My first thought is that changing the get_the_ID() parameter should do the trick, but after adding dummy text it doesn't seem to change anything.

Is this the right place to be looking?

edit:

Pretty knew with hooks, but here's my failed attempt using the code mikesar provided below:

```
add_filter( 'avada_render_post_title', 'short_title_replace' );
function short_title_replace(){

  $customTitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'short-title', true );

  if ( ! empty( $customTitle ) ) {
    echo $customTitle;
  } else {
    echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() ) );
  }
}
```

I've created the custom field, but not sure how to hook into the avada_render_post_title function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, its seems to be the right place to look.

`get_the_ID()` gives you the ID of the current item in the loop.

Do you have the custom field so far?
If yes you can output the "Custom field - Title" with this lines of code:

```
$customTitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'CustomFieldSlug', true );

if ( ! empty( $customTitle ) ) {
    echo $customTitle;
} else {
    echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() ) );
}
```

I dont know what `wp_kses_post()` and the `avada_render_post_title()` function are actual doing. Maybe you have to surround the $customeTitle with these functions, too.

My code example should display the customField Title if its set. Otherwise it should use the normal post title.

---

EDIT:

---

If i understand the render_post_title correctly, you could make a different call to it in the blog-layout.php

```
function avada_render_post_title( $post_id = '', $linked = true, $custom_title ....
```

this part of the function tells us, that we can give a "custom_title" as parameter. Lets give it a try:

```
<?php // Render the post title. ?>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>
```

replace this lines of code with following:

```
<?php // Render the post title. ?>
<?php
    $customTitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'short-title', true );
    if ( ! empty( $customTitle ) ) {
      echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID(), true, $customeTitle ) );
    } else {
      echo wp_kses_post( avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() ) );
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've created the custom field and tested it out with the before_single_post_content hook and its pulling the content properly, but I can't seem to find the proper hook for the blog post title. Do you happen to know?

Comment: I guess its a hook specific to the theme I'm using (Avada):

`<?php
       /**
        * The avada_blog_post_content hook.
        *
        * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_content - 10 (outputs the post content wrapped with a container).
        */
       do_action( 'avada_blog_post_content' );
       ?>`

Not entirely sure how to tap into this though.